# Service Worker FetchEvent.respondWith not working in Safari

Tags: json, safari, fetch-api, service-worker

I'm currently trying to set up a service worker demo for my own understanding.  The intended behavior is for the service workers to check for any requests ending with `.json` and respond with a dummy payload, and otherwise let all requests fall through to the actual server.  In OSX Chrome and Firefox, this works more or less exactly as expected.  In Safari however, the **default** response for the request is always returned, and I can't understand why.

I have two service workers with overlapping scopes: one served from `/test_sw1.js` and one served from `/subdir/test_sw2.js`.  Their contents are thus:

```js
// test_sw1.js
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    const reqUrl = event.request.url
    if (/\.json$/.test(reqUrl)) {
        console.error("REGEX MATCH SUCCEEDED")
        event.respondWith(Response.json({
            "intercepted": "YES",
            "workerId": 1,
            "originalUrl": reqUrl,
        }));
    } else {
        console.error("REGEX MATCH FAILED")
    }
})
```

The contents of `subdir/test_sw2.js` is identical to the above, except with `"workerId": 2` in the response payload.  The idea was to better understand how service workers behave when there are multiple registrations with different but overlapping scopes.

In the root page, I also include a script tag pointing to the following file, `browser_swtest_base.js`, which actually registers the service workers and then tries to fetch a (non-existent) JSON file at `/subdir/test.json`:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/subdir/test_sw2.js')
    .then((reg) => console.warn('SUBDIR service worker registered!', reg))
    .catch(err => console.warn('ERROR: SUBDIR service worker registration failed', err));

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/test_sw1.js')
    .then((reg) => console.warn('TOP-LEVEL service worker registered!', reg))
    .catch(err => console.warn('ERROR: TOP-LEVEL service worker registration failed', err));

fetch("/subdir/test.json").then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status === 200) {
        console.warn("RECEIVED RESPONSE FOR test.json")
        console.warn(resp.text())
    }
})
```

In both Chrome and Firefox, the initial page load shows the `service worker registered!` messages in the console along with a `404` response for the JSON fetch.  That makes sense.  Upon refreshing the page, it shows the registration messages again, **and logs the dummy JSON payload from `test_sw1.js`**.  That surprised me a bit, because I initially expected it to be handled by `sw2`, but it also makes sense -- I had just misunderstood how service worker control relates to scope.

In Safari, **the JSON fetch gets a 404 response every time.**  So I initially thought I must have messed something up and the service workers weren't receiving fetch events.  Nope!  When I check the browser consoles for the top-level worker, **it is outputting `REGEX MATCH SUCCEEDED`** ... but then the `respondWith()` call directly below it does NOTHING.  Same if I navigate directly to `[myorigin]/subdir/test.json` after the subdir service worker is registered.  In Chrome and Firefox, this shows the dummy payload from the `subdir` service worker, with `"workerId": 2`.  In Safari, the console for the `subdir` worker now ALSO outputs `REGEX MATCH SUCCEEDED` ... but the browser shows me a 404 page.  I can also do the same thing fetching an actually-existing .json file, either in the base script or from the console, and Safari outputs the actual contents of that file whereas Chrome and Firefox correctly return the dummy response

So what is going wrong here?  It's not even a particularly complex example, the worker scripts are about as simple as you can get!  The entire point of service workers is to be able to intercept requests like this, and everything I've Googled suggests that Safari should indeed correctly support the ServiceWorker API, but this behavior is complete nonsense.  There are no other error messages in the consoles for the service workers OR the main page.  I'm losing my mind here.

Comment: Which Safari? It seems the static `Response.json()` is only available in Technology Preview and not in the stable version. (As for why the error is swallowed though, I don't know).

Comment: Correct you are, I was just posting my own answer to that effect.  Sure does suck to have spent all that time nicely formatting a question with a self-contained toy example, only to realize the actual error is as stupid as can be... but I guess that's just programming sometimes TT_TT

Answer (score 0):

...Oh, I hate my life, and I also hate Safari *so very much.*

The actual problem here is that Safari DOES NOT SUPPORT the static `Response.json()` method. I had even suspected something like this and explicitly [checked caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_response_json) to reassure myself -- but that's not actually the right feature table, that's for the instance `response.json()` method.  [This is the right table](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_response_json_static) -- so I guess I just had a reading comprehension failure.

The SECONDARY problem here, if you ask me, is that Safari evidently DOESN'T TELL YOU when you have errors in ServiceWorker code.  There's a whole console just for the worker context, but it is completely silent about the issue, even while my explicit `console.error()`s are respected, even if I pull the `const resp = Response.json(...)` into its own line.  If anybody knows a way to rectify THAT issue, I would love to know, but in the meantime... I guess I'll just put my head in my hands.  *sob*

Comment: As much as I feel your pain, I believe your answer would be greatly improved without all the commentary.